# Master_not_discovered_exception error while setting up passwords for user

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

While setting up the password for the built-in ES accounts by logging into the newly setup 3 node cluster `docker exec -it es01 sh` then running `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive --url https://localhost:9200`

**Gets error:**
sh-5.0# bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive --url https://localhost:9200

```
Failed to determine the health of the cluster running at https://localhost:9200
Unexpected response code [503] from calling GET https://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Cause: master_not_discovered_exception
```

Also curl throws below error:

```
sudo curl -X GET 'https://localhost:9200'
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused

sudo curl -X GET 'https://localhost:9216'
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

.P12 Certificates for respective nodes have been transferred. Below elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Have setup a 3-node Elasticsearch cluster using docker-compose. Followed below steps:

1. Initialize a docker swarm. On ES11 run docker swarm init. Follow the instructions to join 12 and 13 to the swarm.
2. Create an overlay network docker network create -d overlay --attachable elastic
3. If necessary, bring down the current cluster and remove all the associated volumes by running docker-compose down -v
4. Create SSL certificates for ES with docker-compose -f create-certs.yml run --rm create_certs
5. Copy the certs for es02 and 03 to the respective servers
6. Use this busybox to create the overlay network on 02 and 03 sudo docker run -itd --name containerX --net [network name] busybox
7. Configure certs on 02 and 03 with docker-compose -f config-certs.yml run --rm config_certs
8. Start the cluster with docker-compose up -d on each server
9. Set the passwords for the built-in ES accounts by logging into the cluster docker exec -it es11 sh then running bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive --url localhost:9200

gets the mentioned error at steps 9. What am I missing?

Below docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  es11:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es11
    environment:
      - node.name=es11
      - transport.port=9316
      - cluster.name=uat-lands
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es12,es13
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es11,es12,es13
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path=${CERTS_DIR}/es11/es11.p12
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path=${CERTS_DIR}/es11/es11.p12
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path=${CERTS_DIR}/es11/es11.p12
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path=${CERTS_DIR}/es11/es11.p12
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config
      - log:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    ports:
      - 9216:9200
      - 9316:9316
    networks:
      - elastic
    dns:
      - es11

    healthcheck:
      test: curl -k -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
  config:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: '/mnt/elasticmount/es11/config'
      o: bind
  log:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: '/mnt/elasticmount/es11/log'
      o: bind

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: The setup were working before to configurate password? Also, did you follow any guide from a post? Can you share link? Or a pastebin link with docker-compose, we don't know what is doing your docker-compose

Comment: It's a newly configured setup. Followed just the steps shared above. Other previous setup envs. working fine were configured with similar steps. Updated the description with docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Try to add "node.master = true" in elasticsearch.yml config file only on es11

Comment: I know it's not the best solution, because in case this node goes down, it won't be available to find master again. You can try to turn off this server and see if the stack goes down or if es12 or es13 is selected as master

Comment: Must to setup your same environment and figure out what's happening :)

Comment: still the same error while- trying to run step 9 above.

Below added in es11 elasticsearch.yml
 cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.master: true

Answer (score 0):

Your cluster is not configured. I don't know, how you created it. Use [elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-file) to start cluster in docker by docker-compose.

Comment: Updated the description with the steps followed to create a cluster. What am i missing?

Comment: If you use swarm you need use swarm service in one network. Each node of elactic is docker service. If you use docker-compose, setup three services in compose file and run them by docker-compose up. You can use compose file and deploy docker stack(set of services).

Comment: As I see you start each elastic node as docker-compose, and each in different files. I don't see es12 and es13 in compose file. If it's true you need add them in one docker compose file (all node in one file) and run it. Docker create all containers in one network and each container can use them name to communicte each other. Or use swarm services.

Comment: This compose file is from es11. Similar goes for es12 & 13. All these configurations are copied from other envs. which have been installed & running fine since many months. So it appears to me, I had missed a step during the setup rather than the configurations. If i attempt to restart the setup process, how do i clear/remove things (cluster,network, volumes, images etc.) already created?

Comment: Can you show logs? I think your containers don't see each other because you have swarm cluster, as I see, and you start conteiners on different hosts by docker-compose. Start by docker stack deploy -c <compose_file> <stack_name>. May be trubls with certs. Try start ELastic cluster without certs, after successful connetction try setup tls.

Comment: to delete things (cluster,network, volumes, images etc.) use docker <object_type> rm <object_ID/name>. To show created object docker <object_type> ls . As example docker volume ls, docker volume rm fb8f7e15dc57c9451e96042a2c0860ea155cccdff31a4ca4c3a11b231eaf0a87