# SSL(curl) connection error in ElasticSearch setup

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, curl, docker-compose

Have setup a 3-node Elasticsearch cluster using docker-compose. Followed below steps:
On one of the master nodes, es11, gets below error, however same curl command works fine on other 2 nodes i.e. es12, es13:

**Error:**

```
curl -X GET 'https://localhost:9316'
    curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Below error in logs:

```
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [es13][SOMEIP:9316][internal:cluster/coordination/join]",
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [es11][SOMEIP:9316] handshake failed. unexpected remote node {es13}{SOMEVALUE}{SOMEVALUE
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.lambda$connectionValidator$6(TransportService.java:468) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$MappedActionListener.onResponse(ActionListener.java:95) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.lambda$handshake$9(TransportService.java:577) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]",
```

https://localhost:9316 on browser gives site can't be reached error as well.It seems SSL certificate as created in step 4 below is having some issues in es11.
Any leads please? OR If I repeat step 4, do i need to copy the certs again to es12 & es13?

Below elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Ports as defined in all 3 nodes docker-compose.yml

```
 environment:
      - node.name=es11
      - transport.port=9316
 ports:
      - 9216:9200
      - 9316:9316
```

1. Initialize a docker swarm. On ES11 run docker swarm init. Follow the instructions to join 12 and 13 to the swarm.
2. Create an overlay network docker network create -d overlay --attachable elastic
3. If necessary, bring down the current cluster and remove all the associated volumes by running docker-compose down -v
4. Create SSL certificates for ES with docker-compose -f create-certs.yml run --rm create_certs
5. Copy the certs for es12 and 13 to the respective servers
6. Use this busybox to create the overlay network on 12 and 13 sudo docker run -itd --name containerX --net [network name] busybox
7. Configure certs on 12 and 13 with docker-compose -f config-certs.yml run --rm config_certs
8. Start the cluster with docker-compose up -d on each server
9. Set the passwords for the built-in ES accounts by logging into the cluster docker exec -it es11 sh then running bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive --url localhost:9316

Comment: I hope you have a really really good reason for using Docker.

Comment: Yes. Respoce from @warkolm makes sense however gets error with 9200 , 9216 for which still seeking a resolution. This related Question at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299644/master-not-discovered-exception-error-while-setting-up-passwords-for-user . please help with the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I cannot help you.  My thinking was this would not be an issue if you were not using Docker.   I'm old school.  I've lived my whole life without Docker.  I have looked into Docker and have failed to understand why I would ever need Docker.  I meant no disrespect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as per your https://discuss.elastic.co thread)

you cannot talk HTTP to the transport protocol port, which you have defined in `transport.port`. you need to talk to port `9200` in the container, which you have mapped to `9216` outside the container

the transport port runs a binary protocol that is not HTTP accessible

Comment: Recieves below error when trying to use 9200 or 9216 on http/s

sudo curl -X GET 'https://localhost:9200'
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused

sudo curl -X GET 'https://localhost:9216'
curl: (35) Encountered end of file..                                                                                                    error when trying to set password with 9200 is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299644/master-not-discovered-exception-error-while-setting-up-passwords-for-user